# How add google font into react-stripe-elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stripe-payments

Hi all I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-cookies-2b7wi1)

I am trying to add `Ralway` google font into my stripe element.

I try this:

App.js

```
    export default function App() {
      const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_FnsOZv49080ssnyO2xn0gCoS");

      const options = {
        elements: {
          fonts: [
            {
              cssSrc:
                "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap"
            }
          ]
        }
      };
      return (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
          <div className="App">
            <PaymentForm />
          </div>
        </Elements>
      );
    }
```

PaymentForm .js

```
     const PaymentForm = () => {
      const stripe = useStripe();
      const elements = useElements();
      const stripeStyle = {
        base: {
          fontFamily: "Raleway",
          fontSize: "16px"
        },
        "::placeholder": {
          color: "green"
        }
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <CardNumberElement
            options={{
          style: stripeStyle
            }}
          />

          <CardExpiryElement options={{ style: stripeStyle }} />

          <CardCvcElement options={{ style: stripeStyle }} />
        </div>
      );
    };
```

But nothing has happened. Please help me figure out how should I change my code.

I looked into following questions ( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239767/how-do-i-add-a-custom-font-to-my-card-element-when-using-react-stripe-elements), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824382/custom-font-src-with-stripe), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274145/how-do-i-apply-a-local-custom-font-to-stripe-elements) ) regarding to fonts for react-stripe-elements but no one of them didn't helped me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is the font-family stylesheet loaded from Google Fonts? I think the issue lies with your `options` variable. There's an extra `elements` hash which is not necessary. It should instead look like:

```
const options = {
  fonts: [{
    cssSrc: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap"
  }]
};

return (
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
    <div className="App">
      <PaymentForm />
    </div>
  </Elements>
)
```